# Which version of jodd-http is supported on jre 7?

Tags: jodd

The current version 5.0.12, I believe, is built for Java 9. Which is the last version of jodd-http to be supported for java 7?

Answer (score 0):

The last version of Jodd for Java **7** is [3.7.1](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/releases/tag/v3.7.1)

Jodd v3.8+, v4.x and v5.x [targets](https://jodd.org/download/) Java **8**.